# Firebase DataSnapshot on how to display result in text view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I had already done on the data update part and now i would like to extract the data and display it based on user input. I have a edit text column for user to key-in and text view to display the data that i stored in Firebase. May i know what is the best coding to work on this ? I found alot of them are using DataSnapshot but they directly read specific value from android studio while i would like to read the value from user input.[https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYrOF.png]
Edittext key in -> 978
TextView shows = 12

```
tv_displayIsland=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_displayIsland);
et_scanIsbn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_scanIsbn);
database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            -- need the coding to read the et_scanIsbn and display in tv_displayIsland--
            }
        }


        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the value of `et_scanIsbn` by doing the following:

```
String sbn = et_scanIsbn.getText().toString();
```

Then you can do:

```
database.child("Island").orderByChild("isbn").equalTo(sbn).addValueEvent....
```

Inside the `onDataChange` you can display the retrieved value inside the `TextView`:

```
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
String island = ds.child("island").getValue(String.class);
tv_displayIsland.setText(island);
```

Comment: the code is working but inside the apps, the textview not displaying the result.

Comment: The text View is not displaying anything? Then check if the id is correct

Comment: Have you checked?

Comment: i will mark but the textview not showing anything, can u help me to check my code as i posted here ?

Comment: check if you are getting a value and check if the id of `textview` is correct.

Comment: i am done with checking but still the same...any possible issue other than that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code now.

```
package com.example.scanning;

public class Scan extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference database;
    TextView tv_displayIsland;
    EditText et_scanIsbn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
        tv_displayIsland = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_displayIsland);
        et_scanIsbn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_scanIsbn);
        String sbn = et_scanIsbn.getText().toString();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        database.child("Island").orderByChild("isbn").equalTo(sbn).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String island = ds.child("island").getValue(String.class);
                    tv_displayIsland.setText(island);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```